# Сортировка по вложенным оценкам (JS)

Tags: javascript, сортировка

Идея такая, есть массив items у него есть свойство rate, представляющий собой массив оценок данных item(у) пользователями.

Функция sortByRating принимает массив item[] и флаг по возрастанию или убыванию производить сортировку.

Какие на ваш взгляд есть альтернативные варианты реализации такой сортировки?

```js
const items = [{
    name: 'first',
    id: 1,
    rate: [{
      id: 1,
      rating: 4,
      userId: 1
    }, {
      id: 2,
      rating: 3,
      userId: 2
    }] // сумма = 7 
  },
  {
    name: 'second',
    id: 2,
    rate: [{
      id: 3,
      rating: 2,
      userId: 1
    }, {
      id: 4,
      rating: 1,
      userId: 2
    }] // cумма = 3
  },
  {
    name: 'third',
    id: 3,
    rate: [{
      id: 5,
      rating: 5,
      userId: 1
    }, {
      id: 6,
      rating: 4,
      userId: 2
    }] // сумма = 9
  },
]

function sortByRating(needToFilter = [], ascending = false) {
  let filtred = null;
  if (ascending) {
    filtred = needToFilter.sort((a, b) => {
      return (
        (a.rate.length > 0 ?
          a.rate.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr.rating, 0) /
          a.rate.length :
          0) -
        (b.rate.length > 0 ?
          b.rate.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr.rating, 0) /
          b.rate.length :
          0)
      );
    });
  } else {
    filtred = needToFilter.sort((a, b) => {
      return (
        (b.rate.length > 0 ?
          b.rate.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr.rating, 0) /
          b.rate.length :
          0) -
        (a.rate.length > 0 ?
          a.rate.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr.rating, 0) /
          a.rate.length :
          0)
      );
    });
  }
  return filtred;
}

console.log(sortByRating(items, false));
console.log(sortByRating(items, true));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const items = getItemsToSort();

function sortByRating(arr = [], asc = false) {
  return arr.sort(function sortItems(item1, item2){
    // Функция getTotalRating ниже: она просто сумирует рейтинг
     const totalRating1 = getTotalRating(item1);
     const totalRating2 = getTotalRating(item2);

     return asc ? 
      (totalRating1 - totalRating2):
      (totalRating2 - totalRating1);
  })
}

console.log('Descending order: ', sortByRating(items)); // third, first, second
console.log('Ascending order: ', sortByRating(items, true)); // second, first, third

function getTotalRating(item){
  return item.rate.reduce((acc, rate) => acc + rate.rating, 0) || 0;
}

// Просто вынес возвращаемый объект в конец, чтоб не отвлекать от реализации функции
function getItemsToSort() {
  return (
    [{
        name: 'first',
        id: 1,
        rate: [{
          id: 1,
          rating: 4,
          userId: 1
        }, {
          id: 2,
          rating: 3,
          userId: 2
        }] // сумма = 7 
      },
      {
        name: 'second',
        id: 2,
        rate: [{
          id: 3,
          rating: 2,
          userId: 1
        }, {
          id: 4,
          rating: 1,
          userId: 2
        }] // cумма = 3
      },
      {
        name: 'third',
        id: 3,
        rate: [{
          id: 5,
          rating: 5,
          userId: 1
        }, {
          id: 6,
          rating: 4,
          userId: 2
        }] // сумма = 9
      },
    ]
  )
};
```